# Is there a GPT-2 implementation that allows me to fine-tune and prompt for text completion?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, openai-gym, gpt-2

I wish to to fine-tune a GPT-2 implementation on some text data. I then want to use this model to complete a text prompt. I can do the first part easily enough using Max Woolf's [gpt-2-simple](https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple) implementation. And [Neil Shepherd's fork](https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2) of OpenAI allows for GPT-2 to be trained on new data and completes text.

However, my corpus is too small to train on and not get gibberish back. Is there any way I can combine the two functions? Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this via a python interface (as opposed to CLI), as I'd like to use pandas for data cleaning and what-have-you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Huggingface's Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) package has a GPT-2 implementation (including pre-trained models) for PyTorch and TensorFlow. You can easily work with them in Python.

Fine-tuning of GPT-2, however, requires a lot of memory and I am not sure is you will be able to do the full backpropagation on that. In that case, you fine-tune just a few highest layers.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've looked at the Higgingface repo and it does offer GPT-2. However––and maybe I'm just being dim––I don't see any functionality for fine-tuning GPT-2, even if it's just the highest layers?

Comment: Once you have it loaded, it behaves like any other PyTorch model. You define a loss function,  an optimizer (to which you need to tell what parameters you need to optimize). Nothing GPT-specific, just plain PyTorch.